# Is Twitter client for the Android platform a good idea for final project?

Tags: android, twitter

I would like to know what is the difficulty level of creating a basic Twitter client for the Android platform, I am asking this because I have to create an android app for my final project and I have doubts as to whether Twitter client would pass as a standard project or not? Some class fellows have discouraged it because they think it's an unoriginal idea and there are plenty of these apps already in the market. The app that I will create is supposed to have a decent interface, timeline database, retrieves updates using a service and has all the general features of the web application like posting a tweet, replying, retweeting and messaging a particular user et cetera et cetera. Please tell me if I should do this, I have to submit the project proposal tomorrow. And if this is not a very good idea, could you please suggest me some ideas?

Comment: at least 2 causes to close this question: off topic and primarily opinion-based

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having an App-for-that doesn't mean there is no point in building one with the same feature. If you can come up with a better functional app having better performance you will hit the jackpot. A neat UI will give you the additional mileage.

In case of your final project, try think ahead of the evaluation period:

1. Can you grow it to a product which brings in money/value?
2. Are you going to gain any expertise/skill which can make you sell yourself for a job?

Comment: Could you please tell me what is the difficulty level of this project considering we have interface, timeline database and usage of variety of techniques and APIs for the app?

Comment: I would say it's a medium level project. Difficulty depends on how complex you need to make the system and how good your skills are.

Comment: This is great. I have medium level skills as of now but I think I am creative enough to create something valuable. Thank you very much for your help. :-)